# is there something like a hubtile (WP7) in win 8 metro style?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

i want to port one of my windows phone 7 apps to the windows 8 metro style plattform.

the problem is, that i **need** a element like the hubtile which i use from the silverlight toolkit for windows phone.

is there something equal in the windows 8 metro style platform? maybe open source like the silverlight toolkit.

**i dont want to add the livetile outside my app, this is easy. i want to have something like hubtile for WP7 for win8. This means a tile which is inside my application.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm right I'm planning to do the same task. I didn't find any reference of a control which performs like a HubTile. Thus, I decided importing the one from the Silverlight Toolkit (for Windows Phone). Luckily it worked almost smoothly, you can see my sample at:

https://github.com/hmadrigal/playground-dotnet/tree/master/MsWinPhone.EmbedFont (tested on Windows 8 RP and Visual Studio 2012 RC)
[image: Capture of the HubTile Sample Application]

Kind regards,
Herber

Answer (score 0):

you can work with the live tiles of course and in several ways. You can use badge notifications, toast notifications, and so on.

I'll suggest you to take a look to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779725.aspx).

And also take a look to those two samples: [App tiles and badge sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) and [Push and periodic notifications client-side sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603)

By the way don't forget to enable the features you need in the package manifest.

Comment: i think you understand my question wrong, i dont want to use the livetile outsite the app e.g. on the start screen. i want to have access on a controle item like the livetile INSIDE my application

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood your question but I think you can use those type of controls inside or hubtile-like. The only example I've seen of these is with the Windows 8 Ads SDK which allows to show content in a "block" inside the app. I've to make some research to find back this example.

Comment: Is it something like this you want to do?

http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/advertising_5F00_drafts.metablogapi/5481.Ap_5F005F00_Ad_5F00_thumb_5F00_7ED31D41.jpg

Comment: Aymeric, dont think so or are the tiles moving like on the start screen of the phone? if they are moving, then yes

Comment: Ok so far I haven't seen it (yet) but if it doesn't exist you still can code it using animations. I'll try to look for this during the week-end. I'll also look if you can ship the hubtile through a WinRT component which will certainly be possible if there is not too much WP7 specific code